Relationship between parameters in MOSFET in CS configuration, voltage divider biased

I have this question.
I have calculated ID, since power budget is given, ID is a simple P/VDD.
Using the ID, RS can also be calculated since it's given that there is a voltage drop of 400mV across RS.
Here the problem starts, I'm just stuck. I don't know how to get other values out since to calculate them, I need one of the other unknowns. Stuck in a cycle.
I do not want a straight answer, just some help that will point me in the right direction in solving this problem. Whatever other problems I have done on the topic have either the resistances given or current across the resistances. Any help would be appreciated.
Another question - Why even give munCox if no W/L is given? I think this should play a part in solving this problem but I don't know.

In case you don't get an answer here, you can delete it from here and ask at Electronics SE.

If power budget is 8mW maximum, then ID might not be P/VDD.
